# Image as Link HTML

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I am putting together a simple website to catalog my DIY projects.  I have a logo that I would like to have sit alone on the front page.  Clicking this image would then link you to a home screen.  I have the link working properly, and the image is centered nicely on the cover page (about 800px wide).  The problem I am facing is that the clickable area for the link seems to extend past the right and left edges of my home screen.

Currently, the code for the image is as follows:

```
img.cent_img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: solid 3px #9966bb;
}
img.cent_img:hover
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: solid 3px #997777;
}
<a href="home.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" class="cent_img" alt="XXX"
TITLE="YYY" width="800" height="330"/></a>
```

Does anyone know why the link is clickable beyond the edges of the image?

N.B. it is only clickable to the left/right.  Above and below the image it functions as expected.

Comment: width=800 : looks like you are putting too much of it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The image is actually 1600px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you center the image, not the link. The image creates margins on left and right side, which are within the `<a>` tag, making that area clickable.

Put your code into a `<div>`, and then center that `<div>`.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eW9V9/

```
#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#logo img
{
    border: solid 3px #9966bb;
}
#logo img:hover
{
    border: solid 3px #997777;
}

<div id="logo">
    <a href="home.html">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="cent_img"         alt="XXX"
TITLE="YYY" width="200" height="100"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to wrap in another element in most cases: http://jsfiddle.net/eW9V9/1/ It works fine without the `<div>` if you just center the `<a>` (though the `<a>` has to be `display: block`)

Comment: Thanks to Adam and Zach L for clarification and examples.